# How to humanly verify $ba^5ba=b^2a^4$ in the group with presentation $\langle a,b : a^7=1, b^3=1, ba^2=ab \rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

The group with presentation $\langle a,b : a^7=1, b^3=1, ba^2=ab \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_7 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$ ([ref.](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/SmallGroup(21,1))).

**Q**: How can I (as a human) verify that $ba^5ba=b^2a^4$ in this group?

Attempting to do this by hand became tedious quickly, although it's more than possible I didn't look in the right direction.

(Perhaps there software that automatically generates a human-readable proof?)

---

I can verify this identity on the computer:  If I understand correctly, this presentation is used for this group for $\mathbb{Z}_7 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$ in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/).  To check this:

```
gap> G:=SmallGroup(21,1);;        
gap> StructureDescription(G);
"C7 : C3"
gap> P:=PresentationViaCosetTable(G);;
gap> TzPrintRelators(P);   
#I  1. f1^3
#I  2. f1*f2^2*f1^-1*f2^-1
```

Here we have $a$ given by `f2` and $b$ given by `f1`.  (I add in the relation $a^7=1$; it makes no difference.)  After setting the variables

```
gap> a:=GeneratorsOfGroup(G)[2];
f2
gap> b:=GeneratorsOfGroup(G)[1];
f1
```

we can then check `b*a^5*b*a=b^2*a^4;` is `true`.  But it doesn't show me how it works, so it's not too helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use $ab=ba^2$ systematically on the left hand side, and $a^7=1$ when it helps, and move the second $b$ to the "front" as follows:

$$ba^5ba=ba^4ba^3=ba^3ba^5=ba^2b=baba^2=b^2a^4$$

Note that you could short cut this by noticing $a^rb=ba^{2r}$ so that you could write immediately $$ba^5ba=b^2a^{11}=b^2a^4$$

Comment: Thanks for that!  It seems easy enough to prove $a^rb=ba^{2r}$ and once you have it, it's trivial.

Comment: While this works here, you are lucky in having relations that immediately give you a normal form. For arbitrary presentations this is hard to hopeless.

Comment: @ahulpke Indeed, but in a two generator group where one of the relations allows you to change the order of generators this is easy to do. I note also for the record that the final relation is equivalent to $a^2=b^{-1}ab$ which shows how the semidirect product works.

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, but such a relation will only exist if the group is metacyclic. So this strategy will work great for small groups, but as soon as they get larger it is unlikely to be applicable. (It is one of the cases where small examples mislead on a generic strategy.)

Comment: @ahulpke The word problem is technically computationally "hard". I once wrote a postgraduate essay on Burnside's problem (whether a finitely generated group in which every element has a finite order must be  a finite group) - this is very hard too (in a less technical sense), and not wholly resolved, I think, for specific orders, though such groups can be infinite.